# Returning result of async method without awaiting - bad idea?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm looking at some code written a while back that is making me very nervous. The general shape of the methods in questions is like this;

```
public Task Foo(...){

   SyncMethod();
   SyncMethod();
   ...
   return AsyncMethod();

}
```

I realize I can just mark the method `async` and do an `await` on the last call, but...do I *have* to? Is this safe to use as is? The sync methods that are called before the last `async` method do not have asynchronous alternatives and the Foo method does not care about the result of the AsyncMethod, so it *looks* like it's ok to just return the awaitable to the caller and let the caller deal with it.

Also, FWIW, the code in question might be called from a thread that's running with an active ASP.NET context, so I'm getting that tingling feeling in my brain that there's some invisible evil that I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I realize I can just mark the method `async` and do an `await` on the last call, but...do I *have* to?

Actually, if you did this, the only change that it would have is that exceptions thrown by either of those synchronous methods would be wrapped into the returned `Task`, while in the current implementation the method would throw without ever successfully returning a `Task`.  The actual effect of what work is done synchronously and what work is done asynchronously is *entirely unaffected*.

Having said that, *both* of the options you've mentioned are worrisome.  Here you have a method that appears to be asynchronous, meaning someone calling it expects it to return more or less *right away*, but in reality the method will run synchronously for some amount of time.

If your two synchronous methods are *really fast* and as a result, you're confident that this very small amount of synchronous work won't be noticeable to any of your callers, then that's fine.  If, however, that work will (even potentially) take a non-trivial amount of time to solve, then you have a problem on your hands.

Having actually asynchronous alternatives for those methods would be best, but as a last resort, until you have a better option, often the best you can manage to do is to `await Task.Run(() => SyncMethod());` for those methods (which of course means the method now needs to be marked as `async`).

Comment: Nice. Note that "the only change..." is not completely true - marking method `async` will also significantly alter the way code for method is generated (linear vs. state machine) which may be concern is some performance critical cases.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, it's the only observable effect of the fact that there is a significant change in the implementation details.  While there is technically a performance cost, that cost is very small; it's *extraordinarily* hard to write an app that really sees it.  In particular, when dealing with asynchronous operations you're inherently dealing with things that *take a long time*.  Code that is expected to run in microseconds *won't be asynchronous in the first place* so in virtually all situations the "cost" of making a method async is dwarfed to the point of not even being measurable.

Comment: @Servy, thanks for that amazing explanation! I keep forgetting about how the throwing/handling of exceptions differ between the traditional Task model and the new async/await model, thanks for that reminder as well.

Comment: Good answer except for the part about `Task.Run`. I'd say a better alternative would be to call the synchronous (presumably blocking) methods directly and document that the method may block even though it has an asynchronous signature. Avoiding `Task.Run` is especially important on ASP.NET.

Comment: @StephenCleary Well, having a method's API indicate that it's asynchronous, while still blocking for a considerable amount of time, is still something that I'd be very concerned about, as it can very easily cause difficult to diagnose problems.  Refactoring the code into multiple methods, one synchronous, one asynchronous, would be another option.  I just don't see most people reading the documentation of every single method before using it, and rather interpreting what it does and how it works based primarily on its signature.

Comment: @Servy: I see your point, but I have the same concern the other way. That is, ASP.NET devs not reading the documentation and thinking that the asynchronous method is truly asynchronous, when it actually uses `Task.Run`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yeah, both are bad, I just suppose that given the choice between making a method perform worse and giving it pretty decent odds of creating actual bugs, I lean towards "poor performing" absent any context.